# HDMI Monitor: Cable not connected, but "visible" in the PC (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, hdmi

I have a Monitor connected via HMDI to my laptop. Then I connected it with a TV via HDMI to watch a Movie. When I connected it back to the Monitor the Monitor shows only:

```
Cable not connected
```

The output of `xrandr` shows:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767 
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1366x768       59.9*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected 1920x1080+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     59.9  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   1680x1050      59.9  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x800       59.9  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1440x576i      50.1  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   1440x480i      60.1     60.1  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

And as far as I know this means that the 2nd screen is recognized by the laptop. I can also see the Desktop when I look at the "desktop switchers".

Does anyone has an idea?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What exactly is your question?